there are two opposed camps, shouting past each other, with clashing incentives

Judging from the results (and here you may assume the usual caveat about my method being “unscientific”), there are two opposed camps, shouting past each other, with clashing incentives: the artists who, rightfully, understanding that systems such as Stable Diffusion are built upon using their work without payment or attribution, are raising alarms, and the AI enthusiasts, companies, and camp followers declaring that the sci-fi future of their dreams has, at long last, arrived.

Source: https://www.thenation.com/article/culture/fordism-ai-art-dall-e/

Does the comma right after "two opposed camps" indicate that "shouting past each other, with clashing incentives" is non-restrictive, non-essential?
Is the grammatical construction of "two opposed camps, shouting past each other, with clashing incentives" "two opposed camps with clashing incentives, which are shouting each other"?


The commas there are discretionary. The clause could be punctuated as follows with no change of meaning:

... there are two opposed camps shouting past each other with clashing incentives: ...

The commas have no bearing whatsoever on how the syntax of the clause is parsed.
The participial clause shouting past each other is not a restrictive clause.

Is "with clashing incentives" part of the participle clause beginning with "shouting"?

It is a supplemental prepositional phrase that offers contextual information that applies to the two opposed camps. Each camp has its incentives and these incentives are opposed to each other: there is no common ground.

There are two camps with clashing incentives and these camps are opposed to each other  and shouting past each other.



I guess that the original sentence of "There are two opposed camps, shouting past each other, with clashing incentives" is "There are two opposed camps with clashing incentives" and that "shouting past each other" has been inserted parenthetically in "There are two opposed camps with clashing incentives". Is this guess wrong?


Is "shouting past each other" a parenthetical insertion?



The punctuation provided in the question makes shouting past each other a parenthetic remark. I think that is clumsy writing and would fix it. Removing the comma helps. Their having clashing incentives is a circumstance that attends their "shouting past each other".  It is why  they're shouting, and shouting past each other. But I wouldn't argue against your understanding of the syntax. However, I would prefer to fix it. A more extreme fix: The two opposing camps who are shouting past each other have clashing incentives.

I. Explaining the comma.


Does the comma right after "two opposed camps" indicate that "shouting past each other, with clashing incentives" is non-restrictive, non-essential?


The comma after two opposed camp is called a setting-off comma. It separates the participle phrase (shouting past each other, with clashing incentives). The participle phrase provides additional but non-essential information.
According to the original sentence, the two opposing camps are:
1."the artists who...are raising alarms" (those who understand that systems like Stable Diffusion use their work without payment or attribution).
2."the AI enthusiasts, companies, and camp followers...has, at long last, arrived" (those who believe the sci-fi future has arrived with AI)
II. Converting the participle phrase into a clause.
Let's consider OP's second question:


Is the grammatical construction of "two opposed camps, shouting past each other, with clashing incentives" "two opposed camps with clashing incentives, which are shouting each other"?


Yes the clause construction is grammatical.
It is possible to transform the participle phrase into a non-restrictive clause that gives further details on the two opposing camps. However, it makes the lengthy sentence even longer.

@Englishgood    It's' an adjective phrase providing additional information about the noun "camps", A noun phrase can contain adjective phrase in it.

"however it makes the lengthy sentence even longer" is the sort of vapid comment one gets from ChatGPT.

@TimR It is my own sentence.

What is the antecedent of "it"?

We are discussing about "the clause construction.'

Please comment on the nature of the "transformation" in your final paragraph.  How is the participle phrase being "transformed"  into a non-restrictive clause?
